# Why can I not save the page when writing to a new blank window?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm doing something really simple: opening a new window with JavaScript and writing to it, in the following way:

```
var w = window.open("", "_blank");
w.document.writeln("blabla");
```

The window opens and shows the text correctly, but Chrome (version 17.0.963.46) doesn't let me save the page, neither with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd>, nor by using the File save menu command, which is greyed.
Am I doing something wrong? Or missing something?

Firefox lets me save the window, opened and written in the same way.

Comment: Looks like a bug, file a bug report at http://new.crbug.com/

Comment: It seems like `about:blank` cannot be saved, that's why. I'm not sure why they disabled it, though.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=31472) in Chrome.

On 2011-05-03 it received the status *WontFix*, meaning this will not be possible unless they change their mind.